# Unity - Set material from Downloaded image instead of resources

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can successfully load a material saved in my Unity project using the code below:

RenderSettings.mat1 = (Material)Resources.Load ("images/img1.jpg", typeof(Material));

However, I am now trying to load an external image by downloading it.

```
Texture2D imgDownloaded;
    string url = "http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/1968081.jpg";

void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(getImg());
        fucntionx ();
    }

public void functionx()
{

    RenderSettings.mat1 = (Material)imgDownloaded;

}

IEnumerator getImg()
{
    yield return 0;

    WWW dl = new WWW(url);

    yield return dl;

    imgDownloaded = dl.texture;
}
```

However, I get the message that I cannot convert from Texture2D to Material .

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yourMaterial.mainTexture = yourTexture;
```

A material consists of many textures, so naturally you can't convert between them.